# MySQL fields <Birthdate, Age>

Tags: mysql

MySQL: Is there a way to create columns in a table called `<Birthdate, Age>`, whereby `<Birthdate>` is of type DATE and `<Age>` is based on `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Birthdate,CURDATE()) AS Age`?

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you just asking if you can create two columns? Why are you using `<` and `>` around column names? Are those characters supposed to be part of the names, or is that just incorrect formatting? Have you tried anything? Please read about [ask] questions here.

Comment: They are called [Generated Columns](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/) on MySQL. Another way is to create a `VIEW` from a query.

Comment: of course yes, but i think that you only need Birthdate, then just determine the "age" (by displaying or getting the value for another function) by calculating it based on the current (or desired) date.

Comment: @EdCottrell My apologies for asking the wrong way.  I'm so new at this that I am literally in "monkey see, monkey do" mode. Yes, I've tried things. Yes, I am asking how to create two columns in the same table, in which a data entry would be a person's D.O.B. into the Birthdate column and the Age column would automatically be calculated. So, for example, I batch enter ten birthdates. I then Query the entire table in the usual form: SELECT * FROM table_name; I'm hoping to see the two columns with the Birthdate I entered and an automatically calculated Age in the second column.

Comment: If you really want an automatic calculation, then see @Shidersz’s comment. But you probably don’t; usually, you’d want to calculate this later, in real-time, like kapitan suggested.